# Почему по-прежнему висит вопрос на английском?

Tags: обсуждение, закрытие-вопросов

Ещё вчера хотел написать, но подумал, что подожду. Но сегодня уже стало совсем любопытно. Почему не закрывают данный [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1517267/how-do-i-search-for-text-on-a-complex-class-object-in-python)?

У него, как видно, куча дизлайков, так плюс ещё по крайней мере одна моя тревога. Обычно, как я вижу, быстро закрывают низкокачественные вопросы, дубликаты или "абстрактные" вопросы, однако же этот вопрос держится бодрячком. В чём его особенность?

Тем более, что другой [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1517951/how-to-run-2-python-files-on-a-hosting) на английском, заданный всего 11 часов назад, уже закрыт.

Comment: Просто к тому времени вопрос не успели закрыть ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯. Этот вопрос лучше вообще удалить, он не только на английском, но там ещё и нет кода. а лишь скрин ошибки или чего-то ещё, хотя можно и не удалять, так как через неделю он автоматически удалится.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Для закрытия требуется 5 голосов участников за закрытие. Данный вопрос набрал только 3 голоса.

Я закрыл, здесь особо нечего обсуждать.

Когда вы наберете [3000 репутации](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges), тоже сможете голосовать за закрытие и переоткрытие вопросов.

Если видите из ряда вон выходящий случай, используйте [сигнал тревоги](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts), чтобы привлечь внимание модератора.

Comment: Также можно написать в чат.